# How to find our what all http calls are made by our java code

Tags: java, web-services, http, jboss

We have many legacy applications which are calling many other legacy web-services. We have a requirement to check if any of our application is calling a particular service.
The tricky part is the server we use is shared among many teams and we cannot go and check their code base to find if they are calling the service. However, the services and applications are deployed on different servers and only talk to each other over HTTP.
So we were thinking in case we can find the HTTP calls coming out of any application. All these applications are deployed on JBoss.
Currently, we can see that calls are coming into the service host and we also know that they are coming from our application host but we are not able to pin point which application is actually calling that service on the service host.

Answer (score 0):

.You can try with enabling access.log

Find the subsystem urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1 element (it's the one with the connectors) and under virtual-server add the following element:

```
                <access-log pattern="%a %t %p %r %s %S %T %{OSSESSIONID}c %{SoapAction}i" rotate="true">
                    <directory path="." relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" />
                </access-log>
```

For example, the virtual-server of a default installation might become the following:

```
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
                <access-log pattern="%a %t %p %r %s %S %T %{OSSESSIONID}c %{SoapAction}i" rotate="true">
                    <directory path="." relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" />
                </access-log>
        </virtual-server>
```